# Hasura expecting a value for non-nullable variable

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, hasura

I'm using Hasura GraphQL to build out a backend for a MVP I'm building. When a user registers a blank profile is created for them via a trigger.

However, if I try to update the profile I get the error:

```
expecting a value for non-nullable variable: id of type: uuid! in variableValues
```

This is the mutation that is called inside React:

```
mutation updateUserProfile(
        $id: uuid!
        $user_profile: user_profile_set_input!
    ) {
        update_user_profile_by_pk(
            pk_columns: { id: $id }
            _set: $user_profile
        ) {
            twitter
        }
    }
```

The table an id column with following criteria: uuid, primary key, unique, default: gen_random_uuid()

I've also set the column presets to use x-hasura-user-id from the session variable but it still complains about it. This id is generated and should never be changed, so I'm not sure why it's asking me to pass it in?

Thanks all.

Comment: read schema/types, input type for this mutation - if `id` required then you must pass it ;)

Comment: I'm pretty new to Hasura + GraphQL so just trying to find my way around, but this confuses me somewhat. I do pass the id though? I've edited above.

Comment: this is a mutation declaration only, nothing about really passed variables - check network request body for `variables`